# How can I programmatically test an HTTP connection?

Tags: java, http, url, httpconnection

Using Java, how can I test that a URL is contactable, and returns a valid response?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/about
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The solution as a unit test:

```
public void testURL() throws Exception {
    String strUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/about";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.connect();

        assertEquals(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, urlConn.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error creating HTTP connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: @David: No, often people ask questions they already know the answer for, just to provide more useful content for SO.

Comment: Far enough, apologize for the comment in that case. And thanks for sharing the solution then...

Comment: @brass-kazoo I got connection refused exception :(

Comment: Isn't it also necessary to call `urlCon.disconnect()` in a `finally` block?  And maybe also completely consume the `InputStream`?

Comment: If you use it on a comuter available on your network but with no webserver running, this method will hang. You need to use setConnectTimeout and/or setReadTimeout on the HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 7):

Since java 5 if i recall, the InetAdress class contains a method called isReachable(); so you can use it to make a ping implementation in java. You can also specify a timeout for this method. This is just another alternative to the unit test method posted above, which is probably more efficient.

Comment: isReachable only tests that you can reach the site, not that the site is actually running (e.g., returning 200 rather than 500 or the like).

Comment: Also, unit tests are required more to be thorough, than efficient. :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(new InetSocketAddress("http://stackoverflow.com/about", 80).isUnresolved());
```

delivers *false* if page is reachable, which is a precondition.

In order to cover initial question completely, you need to implement a *http get* or *post*.

Answer (score -12):

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator;

public class ValidateUrlExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();

        //valid URL
        if (urlValidator.isValid("http://www.mkyong.com")) {
            System.out.println("url is valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("url is invalid");
        }

        //invalid URL
        if (urlValidator.isValid("http://invalidURL^$&%$&^")) {
            System.out.println("url is valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("url is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
url is valid
url is invalid
```

source : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-validate-url-in-java/

Comment: -1. This does not answer the question at all : the code you posted only checks if the URL is valid, not if the host under that URL is reachable or gives a given response.

Comment: This is a misleading answer -1 for that.