# Determining Client Internet Connection (InternetGetConnectedState() lies)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

It seems I am not the only one to have discovered this:
http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=72771

Actually both:

InternetGetConnectedState

InternetGetConnectedStateEx

are not reporting correctly.
When I am connected, it returns 0x12 and when I an not connected it returns 0x10
(0x10 is not defined)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384705(VS.85).aspx

Anyone care to take a guess at the definition of 0x10 in WinXP SP3?

Having read on this forum some suggestions for testing for the presence of an internet connection (C/C++) like
[How can I programmatically test an HTTP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285860/how-can-i-programmatically-test-an-http-connection)

I would write a WinHTTP function to return the headers of the servers main webpage, except the server I want to test a connection to, only runs CGI apps. I would prefer to not waste precious server memory and processor resources confirming thousands of clients connections.

any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

InternetGetConnectedState/Ex() returns a DWORD that is a bitmask of multiple values.  The value 0x12 is a combination of `INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN` (0x02) and `INTERNET_CONNECTION_RAS_INSTALLED` (0x10).  So, when you are connected, `INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN` is being reported, and when you are disconnected, `INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN` is being omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Sure 0x10 is not a combination of the possible flags?

e.g. here I found [WIN API Internet Get Connected State](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/12026/win-api-internet-get-conn.aspx)

```
INTERNET_CONNECTION_RAS_INSTALLED = 0x10
```