# Check HTTP connection to a URL (Android)

Tags: java, android, http, url, connection

I am trying to check a connection to a URL using HTTP in an app...

Process:

User clicks buttons, app sends a get request and then if successful it will return true, else false.

```
 final Button mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.httpcheck);
    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
                try{
                    URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.google.co.uk");
                    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
                    connection.connect();
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

[image: Example]

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: And what the question? Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-a-http-url-for-availability

Comment: You may want to move your url connection code into an `AsyncTask`

Comment: Updated OP, I basically want to check a connection to a URL, and for it to return connection successful/Not succesful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating  a method in your own click instead of calling the method. you should put the isConntectedToServer method in an asynctask and call the AsyncTask in the onClick

```
final Button mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.httpcheck);
mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

      //call asynctask containing isConntectedToServer method here

    }
});

//put this code in an asynctask and call it there
 public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
            try{
                URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.google.co.uk");
                URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
                connection.connect();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do I use a asynctask? Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: I suggest reading the android developer  link i have pasted here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. It will provide all the details on asynctask with an example on how to use it.  In a nut shell, an asynctask has 2 main parts: 1. doInBackground method to make a network call to execute a function or get data (where you will use your IsConnectedToServer method) and 2. onPostExecute to store data and update the UI thread.

Comment: This always produce exception of NetworkOnMainthread exception

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an answer of a similar question. You just have to change the function to make your function return a boolean. Hope that helps you.

[Test an HTTP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285860/how-can-i-programmatically-test-an-http-connection)